# How do I launch Jupyter Notebook in WSL using PowerShell?

Tags: bash, powershell, jupyter-notebook, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

What I want to do is to create a shortcut for Jupyter Notebook which has to run in WSL (because all my python packages are there). For this AFAIK I should create PowerShell script which runs WSL with command to launch Jupyter Notebook, something like this:

```
wsl -e bash -c "jupyter notebook"
```

But this command gives `bash: jupyter: command not found` although if I do it step by step, it launches Jupyter:

```
PS C:\Users\Artem> wsl
(base) artem@LAPTOP-O4C3S1UK:/mnt/c/Users/Artem$ jupyter notebook
```

All tested commands suffer from one of these problems:

1. bash cannot find the command (neither `jupyter` or `anaconda`)
2. Some terminal laucnhes and instantly disappears

I am not proficient enough in PowerShell/WSL scripting so asking for advice how to do it properly.

P.S. I guess I can install jupyter for Windows and add kernels from WSL, but I want to know if problem can be solved in the way described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like required initializations are performed in your `~/.bashrc` file, which `bash` by default only loads in *interactive* sessions, not when you submit a command to execute with `-c`.

However, you can explicitly tell `bash` to consider a session interactive, using the `-i` option.

Therefore, try the following (note the `-i`):

```
wsl -e bash -ic "jupyter notebook"
```

Comment: Thank you for clear explanation! I've checked the `~/.bashrc`, there is some `conda` initialization, by which I've installed Jupyter, so that was the problem.

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful, @QuadR; my pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it by using the  absolute path of jupyter.
Here is how to do that

```sh
# this code should run in WSL
# get the absolute path of jupyter
which jupyter
# output
# /home/sheep/miniconda3/envs/flask/bin/jupyter
```

When you run the code in WSL, you will get the absolute path of jupyter.

Then, you will be able to lanuch jupyter by running `wsl -e bash -c "/home/sheep/miniconda3/envs/flask/bin/jupyter notebook"` in PowerShell.

Note: `/home/sheep/miniconda3/envs/flask/bin/jupyter` is the absolute path of jupyter in my computer.You should replace it with yours.